# No "><|" key on keyboard - remap other key?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, special-characters, remapping

I've got an older Thinkpad but it has no <kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>|</kbd> key (which is supposed to be to the right of the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key). This makes terminal work really hard.

Is there any way to map for example my <kbd>Z</kbd> key in a way, that if I press <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> I get a <kbd>|</kbd>? 
Same with <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: So, your keyboard doesn't have the `<` key, `>` key, or the `|` key? These are three separate things that you're trying to rebind other keys to right?

Comment: @OwenHines The answer may involve that, but the OP is used to an international keyboard with ><| on the same key. See the diagrams at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key

Comment: @chaskes Ah! I didn't even know about that. The question makes a lot more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Sry, yes, it is a german keyboard. If you press the key, it will yield "<", Shift+Key will yield ">" and AltGr-key "|".

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself: Using the tool xmodmap I was able to remap

- <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to <kbd><</kbd>,
- <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to <kbd>></kbd> and
- <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>|</kbd>.